# Erro ao inserir dados de um CSV em MySQL com Python

Tags: mysql, python, csv

estou escrevendo um código em Python que insere os dados de um CSV em uma tabela MySQL.

```
if os.path.isfile('\\offline.csv'):

        try:
                csv = csv.reader(open('\\offline.csv', encoding='utf-8'))
                for row in csv:
                    conn = connect()
                    cursor = conn.cursor()
                    query = "INSERT INTO maquina(processador, mb_fabricante, mb_modelo, mb_num_serie, sis_hostname, sis_versao_sistema, sis_data_instalacao, rede_ipv4, rede_macaddress, rede_srv_dns, memoria_ram, total_hd, nome_tecnico)VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
                    cursor.execute(query, row)                    
                    conn.commit()
                    print('sucesso csv')
                    cursor.close()
                    conn.close()
        except Exception as erro:
                    print('erro csv', erro)
```

O problema que ocorre é o seguinte: os dados do cabeçalho que são os nomes das colunas do banco são inseridos como registros, mas os dados seguintes, que seriam para ser inseridos retornam o erro: `csv not enough arguments for format string`.
O CSV é esse:
[image]

Eu gostaria de ignorar os dados do cabeçalho e apenas inserir a linha seguinte. Já tentei apagar manualmente o cabeçalho mas o erro persiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A princípio o código está OK. Pelo print do arquivo .csv acredito que o erro seja a linha em branca entre o cabeçalho e a primeira linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloca uma verificação se a linha é vazia

```
for row in csv:
    if len( row ) == 0:
        continue
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, o erro era referente a linha em branco. Perdi quase dois dias quebrando a cabeça. Muito agradecido.

Comment: Acontece muito isso com todos :)